# install python package on heroku without pypi support

Tags: python, django, heroku, pyke

I am trying install a Django app on Heroku. My app needs [pyke3](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/). The recommended way for installing pyke3 is to download pyke3-1.1.1.zip https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyke/files/pyke/1.1.1/ and then install (into a virtualenv if desired) using the instructions on http://pyke.sourceforge.net/about_pyke/installing_pyke.html. How do I install pyke3 on heroku? Is there a way to add this to the requirements.txt, and how will heroku know where to get the pyke3 zip file?

Comment: Your question is not that much clear. Also you asked too many questions out of one question. Try to explore yourself first before asking and be specific.

Answer (score 1):

From pip's docs:

> pip supports installing from PyPI, version control, local projects, and directly from distribution files.

So, pip supports installing packages directly from links. All you have to do is put the link to the required package in your requirements file.

To download the package `pyke3-1.1.1.zip`, add this link in your requirements:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyke/files/pyke/1.1.1/pyke3-1.1.1.zip/download
```

Comment: I tried this and it results in calling 'python setup.py install'. The installation instructions for pyke suggests calling build before install on setup.py. Will not calling build command have any -ve impact? It seems that build in this case copies all the files in the build directory, which is then used by install. Since there isnt any compilation (of native modules), not calling build may be OK. But I could be missing out something. Also noticed that structure of egg-info is different - calling both build+install results in a file where as just calling install results in a directory.

Comment: @PankajJain According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#splitting-the-job-up), `"running the install command first runs the build command`. So, if you just run `install`, it will automatically run `build`. But anyway, if you're doubtful, you should make a new virtualenv and install this package there and test your code against this installation.